# How do I put a computed value in a table prop when using element ui

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I am using vuejs and element ui for my frontend. I want to render a table that has a date that is in unix format. 
I am using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to display the date in a readable format.

I am having issues using moment js inside a table prop. It does not render anything.

Here is my sample code for the table.

```
    <el-table
            :data="data"
            style="width: 100%"
          >
            <el-table-column
              prop="name"
              label="Name"
              width="180"
            />
            <el-table-column
              prop="address"
              label="address"
              width="180"
            />
            <el-table-column
              prop="email"
              label="Email"
            />
            <el-table-column
              prop="moment(due)"
              label="Last Activity"
            />
    </el-table>
```

If I remove the moment js function call, it shows the date in unix format, I need it to render the date in human readable format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the prop should represent the date key from the table data. Then you can create a template slot within the table column you want to add your moment. I don't know how you are fetching your table data but it should work anyways.

```
 <el-table-column prop="created_at" label="Joined">
   <template slot-scope="props">
     {{ props.row.created_at | moment("MMMM Do YYYY") }}
   </template>
 </el-table-column>
```

Comment: I was able to achieve using this